# Querying DocumentDB using a propery by its name

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I tried

```
CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(this.collection.DocumentsLink)
.Where(doc => doc.GetPropertyValue<string>(CollectionNameProperty) == collectionName)
```

But it says, that GetPropertyValue is not supported.

I don't have POCO types for documents, as schema is dynamic. Is DocumentDB SQL my only option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL is the best option since LINQ requires type-binding.

You can alternatively query using the type of Dictionary, then convert to Document (either by reading as an ExpandoObject, or by converting using JsonConvert). But SQL is going to be relatively cleaner:

```
var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Dictionary<string, object>>(collectionLink)
.Where(c => (string)c[propertyName] == propertyValue);

Dictionary<string, object> documentAsDictionary = query.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
Document document = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Document>(
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(documentAsDictionary));
```

Comment: How would i receive multiple items instead of FirstOrDefault?

Comment: This only return the first level properties as a Dictionary, but doesn't cover the case when you have nested objects or nested array of ojects... @Aravind Krishna R. How would you handle this? Is there any way to take raw JSON string and deserialize it manually?